# Type mismatch error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I am getting:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.openqa.selenium.WebElement to WebElement

for the below code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class WebElement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin");

        WebElement emailField = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId"));


    }

}
```

Comment: Change the name of class it causes ambiguity when you access or try to import the WebElement for locating your element

Answer (score 4):

By naming your class `WebElement`, you are *shadowing the imported `WebElement`*.

Pick a different name for your class.

Comment: In addition, just for good Java purposes, don't `import org.openqa.selenium.*;` Instead, explicitly import only the elements you need.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of class it causes ambiguity when you access or try to import the `WebElement`  for locating your element